# How to make a TCP server that uses DbContext to save data?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, tcp, dbcontext, tcpserver

I'm developing a TCP Server that receive data and store it in a database. I started a MVC solution, make a TCPListener Class and instance it in Startup.cs.
Now, I want to save data, but i found a problem: I can't use DbContext because i have to inject it to the class.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

I tried to make the class TCPListener as singleton, but the DataContext must be Singleton too.

Startup.cs

```cs
        public static TCPListener TCPListener { get; set; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.UseSqlServer(Startup.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
            Startup.TCPListener = new TCPListener();//Here, I should pass an DataContext 
...
```

TCPListener.cs

```cs
        private readonly DataContext dataContext;
        private List<Connection> connection { get; set; }

        public TCPListener(DataContext dataContext)
        {
            this.dataContext = dataContext;
...
```